Espacio en blanco en extremo derecho de barra de estado que no se de donde sale
Recientemente dentro de mi proyecto he implementado una barra de estado y quiero que la etiqueta que dice "None2" ocupe todo el espacio resultante, pero  está siendo ocupado por ese espacio que desconozco realmente de dónde sale.
No se como hacer para que las etiquetas que contienen "None3", "None4" y "None5" vayan hasta el final de la ventana y el espacio resultante sea ocupado por "None2". Ya jugué por las QSizePolicy, sin embargo no encuentro cual es el problema. El diseño lo hice en QtDesigner pero no se que causa este comportamiento si alguien me puede ayudar cualquier idea sera bienvenida


Código
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        def close_():
            """
            this internal window is becasue the variable is not accesible
            for that reason we are cosing inside the application
            """
            MainWindow.close()

        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(QIcon(r"Icons/Main_logo.png"))

        MainWindow.resize(963, 698) # Initialize with resize
        margins = QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)  # setting the margins to don't shoe margins

        self.labelList = [] # will contain the labels on the list

        # Tray icon
        self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon()
        self.tray_icon.setIcon(QIcon(r"Icons/Main_logo.png"))

        # Defined the central widget to put my widgets
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow) # Define the widget
        self.centralwidget.setContentsMargins(margins)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        # Define the chorizontal Layout
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget) # Horizontal layout, parent central widget
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(margins)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")


        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget) #  widget container has parent central widget
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")

        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(margins)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        # Defining the TabWidget over this Widget we are going to do the notebook
        self.tabWidget = Tab()
        self.tabWidget.s_noTabs.connect(close_)  # Conectada a una funcion interna de la función
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tabWidget.addTab()

        # Creating Vertical layout
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.widget) # Give the space to display the tabs

        # Here is the MenuBar and the rest of the QActions
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 963, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuEdit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuEdit.setObjectName("menuEdit")
        self.menuView = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuView.setObjectName("menuView")
        self.menuZoom = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuView)
        self.menuZoom.setObjectName("menuZoom")
        self.menuTrackMode = self.menubar.addMenu("&Track Mode")
        self.menuTrackMode.setObjectName("menuTrackMode")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        # Statrus bar
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        # Craeting the Label tabs
        self.statusLabel_1 = QLabel()
        self.statusLabel_2 = QLabel()
        self.statusLabel_3 = QLabel()
        self.statusLabel_4 = QLabel()
        self.statusLabel_5 = QLabel()

        # Giving name on the list to work individualy
        self.statusLabel_1.setText("None1")  # Label for the colum| rows
        self.statusLabel_1.setMaximumWidth(200)
        self.statusLabel_1.setMinimumWidth(150)
        self.statusLabel_1.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)

        self.statusLabel_2.setText("None2")  # Label for the total Characters
        self.statusLabel_2.setMinimumWidth(300)
        self.statusLabel_2.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)

        self.statusLabel_3.setText("None3")  # Label for the Zoom percentage
        self.statusLabel_3.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.statusLabel_3.setMinimumWidth(50)
        self.statusLabel_3.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)

        self.statusLabel_4.setText("None4")  # Label for the operative system
        self.statusLabel_4.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.statusLabel_4.setMinimumWidth(50)
        self.statusLabel_4.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)

        self.statusLabel_5.setText("None5")  # Label for the codifications characters unicode
        self.statusLabel_5.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.statusLabel_5.setMinimumWidth(50)
        self.statusLabel_5.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)

        # Append the label to a list in order to work with them
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.statusLabel_1)
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.statusLabel_2)
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.statusLabel_3)
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.statusLabel_4)
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.statusLabel_5)

        self.actionNew_Tab = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew_Tab.setShortcutContext(QtCore.Qt.WindowShortcut)
        self.actionNew_Tab.setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu(False)
        self.actionNew_Tab.setObjectName("actionNew_Tab")
        self.actionNew_Tab.setIcon(QIcon(r"Icons/NewDocument.png"))
        self.actionNew_Tab.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+N"))
        self.actionNew_Window = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew_Window.setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu(False)
        self.actionNew_Window.setObjectName("actionNew_Window")
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionOpen.setIcon(QIcon(r"Icons/openFile.png"))
        self.actionOpen.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+O"))
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.actionSave.setIcon(QIcon("Icons/Save.png"))
        self.actionSave.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+S"))
        self.actionSave_as = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave_as.setObjectName("actionSave_as")
        self.actionSave_as.setIcon(QIcon("Icons/save-file_10057642.png"))
        self.actionSave_as.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Shift+Ctrl+S"))
        self.actionSave_all = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave_all.setObjectName("actionSave_all")
        self.actionSave_all_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave_all_2.setObjectName("actionSave_all_2")
        self.actionPage_Set_Up = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionPage_Set_Up.setObjectName("actionPage_Set_Up")
        self.actionPrint = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionPrint.setObjectName("actionPrint")
        self.actionClose_Tab = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose_Tab.setObjectName("actionClose_Tab")
        self.actionClose_Tab.setIcon(QIcon("Icons/closeTab.png"))
        self.actionClose_Tab.setShortcut("Ctrl+W")
        self.actionClose_Window = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose_Window.setShortcut("Shift+Ctrl+W")
        self.actionClose_Window.setObjectName("actionClose_Window")
        self.actionExit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName("actionExit")
        self.actionUndo = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionUndo.setObjectName("actionUndo")
        self.actionUndo.setIcon(QIcon("Icons/undo.png"))
        self.actionUndo.setShortcut("Ctrl+Z")
        self.actionUndo.setEnabled(False)
        self.actionRedo = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionRedo.setObjectName("actionRedo")
        self.actionRedo.setText("Redo")
        self.actionRedo.setEnabled(False)
        self.actionRedo.setShortcut("Ctrl+Y")
        self.actionRedo.setIcon(QIcon("Icons/redo.png"))
        self.actionCut = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionCut.setObjectName("actionCut")
        self.actionCut.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+X"))
        self.actionCut.setIcon(QIcon("Icons/cut.png"))
        self.actionCopy = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionCopy.setObjectName("actionCopy")
        self.actionCopy.setIcon(QIcon("Icons/icons8-copy-94.png"))
        self.actionCopy.setShortcut("Ctrl+C")
        self.actionPaste = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionPaste.setObjectName("actionPaste")
        self.actionPaste.setIcon(QIcon("Icons/paste.png"))
        self.actionPaste.setShortcut("Ctrl+V")
        self.actionFind = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionFind.setObjectName("actionFind")
        self.actionFind_next = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionFind_next.setObjectName("actionFind_next")
        self.actionFind_previous = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionFind_previous.setObjectName("actionFind_previous")
        self.actionReplace = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionReplace.setObjectName("actionReplace")
        self.actionGo_to = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionGo_to.setObjectName("actionGo_to")
        self.actionDelete_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionDelete_2.setObjectName("actionDelete_2")
        self.actionDelete_2.setIcon(QIcon("Icons/clear.png"))
        self.actionSelect_all = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSelect_all.setObjectName("actionSelect_all")
        self.actionTime_Date = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionTime_Date.setObjectName("actionTime_Date")
        self.actionTime_Date.setIcon(QIcon("Icons/time.png"))
        self.actionFont = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionFont.setObjectName("actionFont")
        self.actionZoom_in = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionZoom_in.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl++"))
        self.actionZoom_in.setIcon(QIcon(r"Icons\zoom-in.png"))
        self.actionZoom_in.setObjectName("actionZoom_in")
        self.actionZoom_out = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionZoom_out.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+-"))
        self.actionZoom_out.setIcon(QIcon(r"Icons\zoom-out.png"))
        self.actionZoom_out.setObjectName("actionZoom_out")
        self.actionStatus_bar = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionStatus_bar.setObjectName("actionStatus_bar")
        self.actionStatus_bar.setCheckable(True)
        self.actionStatus_bar.setChecked(True)
        self.actionWord_wrap = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionWord_wrap.setObjectName("actionWord_wrap")
        self.actionEnableTrackMode = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionEnableTrackMode.setCheckable(True)
        self.actionEnableTrackMode.setObjectName("actionTrack_mode")
        self.actionEnableTrackMode.setShortcut("Ctrl+T")


        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNew_Tab)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNew_Window)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave_as)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave_all_2)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionPage_Set_Up)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionPrint)
        self.menuFile.addSeparator()
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionClose_Tab)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionClose_Window)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionUndo)
        self.menuEdit.addSeparator()
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionRedo)
        self.menuEdit.addSeparator()
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionCut)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionCopy)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionPaste)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionDelete_2)
        self.menuEdit.addSeparator()
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionFind)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionFind_next)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionFind_previous)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionReplace)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionGo_to)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionSelect_all)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionTime_Date)
        self.menuEdit.addAction(self.actionFont)
        self.menuZoom.addAction(self.actionZoom_in)
        self.menuZoom.addAction(self.actionZoom_out)
        self.menuView.addAction(self.menuZoom.menuAction())
        self.menuView.addAction(self.actionStatus_bar)
        self.menuView.addAction(self.actionWord_wrap)
        self.menuTrackMode.addAction(self.actionEnableTrackMode)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuEdit.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuView.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuTrackMode.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "QNotePad")) # Define the window Title
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuEdit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.menuView.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "View"))
        self.menuZoom.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Zoom"))
        self.actionNew_Tab.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Tab"))
        self.actionNew_Window.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Window"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.actionSave_as.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save as "))
        self.actionSave_all.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save all"))
        self.actionSave_all_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save all"))
        self.actionPage_Set_Up.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Page Set Up"))
        self.actionPrint.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Print"))
        self.actionClose_Tab.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close Tab"))
        self.actionClose_Window.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close Window"))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.actionUndo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Undo"))
        self.actionCut.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cut"))
        self.actionCopy.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Copy"))
        self.actionPaste.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Paste"))
        self.actionFind.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Find"))
        self.actionFind_next.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Find next"))
        self.actionFind_previous.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Find previous"))
        self.actionReplace.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Replace"))
        self.actionGo_to.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Go to"))
        self.actionDelete_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete"))
        self.actionSelect_all.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Select all"))
        self.actionTime_Date.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Time/Date"))
        self.actionFont.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Font"))
        self.actionZoom_in.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Zoom in"))
        self.actionZoom_out.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Zoom out"))
        self.actionStatus_bar.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Status bar"))
        self.actionWord_wrap.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Word wrap"))
        self.actionEnableTrackMode.setText("Enable Track Mode")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


En principio lo único que necesitas es hacer uso del parámetro stretch de addWidget()/addPermanentWidget():

El parámetro stretch se utiliza para calcular un tamaño adecuado
para el widget a medida que la barra de estado crece y se encoge. El
factor de estiramiento por defecto es 0, es decir, dar al widget un
espacio mínimo.

Simplemente asignado un stretch de 1 para el widget "None2" deberias conseguir el resultado deseado.
Ejemplo basado en tu código:
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QStatusBar, QSizePolicy

 
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
        self.setWindowTitle("Barra de Estado")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 600, 400)

        # Status bar
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.statusbar.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        # Craeting the Label tabs
        self.statusLabel_1 = QLabel()
        self.statusLabel_2 = QLabel()
        self.statusLabel_3 = QLabel()
        self.statusLabel_4 = QLabel()
        self.statusLabel_5 = QLabel()

        # Giving name on the list to work individualy
        self.statusLabel_1.setText("None1")  # Label for the colum| rows
        self.statusLabel_1.setMaximumWidth(200)
        self.statusLabel_1.setMinimumWidth(100)

        self.statusLabel_2.setText("None2")  # Label for the total Characters
        self.statusLabel_2.setMinimumWidth(300)

        self.statusLabel_3.setText("None3")  # Label for the Zoom percentage
        self.statusLabel_3.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.statusLabel_3.setMinimumWidth(50)

        self.statusLabel_4.setText("None4")  # Label for the operative system
        self.statusLabel_4.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.statusLabel_4.setMinimumWidth(50)

        self.statusLabel_5.setText("None5")  # Label for the codifications characters unicode
        self.statusLabel_5.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.statusLabel_5.setMinimumWidth(50)

        # Append the label to a list in order to work with them
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.statusLabel_1)
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.statusLabel_2, stretch=1)
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.statusLabel_3)
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.statusLabel_4)
        self.statusbar.addWidget(self.statusLabel_5) 
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
    sys.exit()


Puedes  usar también addPermanentWidget() que emplaza los widgets partiendo del extremo derecho de la barra, si no es un problema que sean widgets permanentes (no serán ocultados por los mensajes temporales).

Tu respuesta ha sido más efectiva y realmente me funcionó demasiado, agradzco mucho tu apoyo

He solucionado el problema utilizando la propiedad addPermanentWidget, a los labels para que se vayan al lado derecho, gracias
